# Is there a solution for using ethers.js or web3.js in a Nuxt 3 project?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, nuxt3

I am currently working on an application using Nuxt 3 and I am trying to integrate with either ethers.js or web3.js to interact with an Ethereum blockchain. However, I have encountered errors and have not been able to get either package to work with Nuxt 3.

I have tried several ways to integrate these packages, but so far, I have not been successful. I have encountered errors that I have attached as screenshots to this question.

I am wondering if anyone has been successful in integrating either ethers.js or web3.js with Nuxt 3 and could provide guidance on how to do so. Alternatively, are there any other packages or approaches that could be used instead of these two packages?

Screenshots:

[image: Insert screenshots of errors encountered when trying to integrate ethers.js or web3.js with Nuxt 3]

Answer (score 1):

You probably going to need to use the vite's polyfill plugin.

Install **vite-plugin-node-polyfills**:

```
yarn add vite-plugin-node-polyfills
```

Then go into your **nuxt.config.ts** file and add this plugin to **Vite**:

```
import { nodePolyfills } from "vite-plugin-node-polyfills";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
...
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      nodePolyfills(),
    ],
  },
...
}
```